# Get array of all named group pattern in URLPattern

Tags: regex, url, url-routing, url-pattern

Given the following URLPattern:

`new URLPattern('/path/example/:name/:age')`

I am looking to return an array of all named groups. `['name', 'age']`

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLPattern/URLPattern
- https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp

I don't see a simple library / class to do this?

I need this to take into account all supported url paths for instance `/users/:id/:tab(home|photos|bio)`.

One way to do this that does not satisfy /users/:id/:tab(home|photos|bio) is to feed the url back into itself like this:

```js
const x = new URLPattern({ pathname: '/path/example/:name/:age' })
const r = x.exec('https://localhost:3000/path/example/:name/:age')
console.log(Object.keys(r.pathname.groups))
[ "name", "age" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`(?<=\/:)\w+/g`

`\w+` means search for one or more word character from `a` to `z` or from `A` to `Z` or from `0` to `9` or an underscore `_`, then `(?<=\/:)` it insures that the string is preceded by a `/:` but it does not include the value of `/:` as part of the result.

```js
var x = "https://localhost:3000/path/example/:name/:age";

var arr = x.match(/(?<=\/:)\w+/g);

console.log(arr);
```